# Unity How to Serialize Map Data

Tags: unity-game-engine, serialization, deserialization

use  2019.1.8f1 ver

I've been referring to a lot of information, but an unknown error bothers me.

Error
SerializationException: Type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' in Assembly 'UnityEngine.CoreModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Map
{
    public Node[,] nodes;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Node
{
    public GameObject tile;

    public bool walkable;
    public Vector3 worldPosition;
    public int gridX;
    public int gridY;

    public int gCost;
    public int hCost;
    public int FCost { get { return gCost + hCost; } }

    public Node(bool _walkable, Vector3 _worldPosition, int _gridX, int _gridY)
    {
        walkable = _walkable;
        worldPosition = _worldPosition;
        gridX = _gridX;
        gridY = _gridY;

    }

}


[System.Serializable]
public class Grid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Node[,] grid;


public void SaveMapData()
{
    Debug.Log("Save");
    FileStream stream = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + path);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

    Map map = new Map();
    map.nodes = grid.grid;

    bf.Serialize(stream, map);
    stream.Close();
 }
```

Comment: `MonoBehaviour` is serialzable on its own btw so `[Serializable]` is redundant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Node` class references the `GameObject` class here:
`public GameObject tile;`

The best solution would be to get rid of that reference. This would also improve the decoupling of your model from the view.

Or try the `[NonSerialized]` attribute as a quick fix:
`[NonSerialized] public GameObject tile;`

Comment: Thank you.
Unity's own class, Structure is doing NonSerialize.
It's working.